# Can't figure this error out?

Tags: sql, oracle

Code :

```
SELECT * FROM Grade   
WHERE grade = ‘MG’ ‘1-9’  
SELECT * StaffNo, Name, DOB, ReportsTo,  
FROM Staff  
ORDER BY DOB DESC;
```

I keep getting

> ORA-00911: invalid character

is this a problem with the code?

Comment: You need to terminate the first SELECT with a semicolon `;`

Answer (score 2):

Couple of problems -

1.You either need to do a `UNION` between the first and second `SELECT` statement, in which case the columns (datatypes) on both the `SELECT`s should match. Also, one of the columns should be `DOB`

```
SELECT StaffNo, Name, DOB, ReportsTo  --you can do * here if Grade has exactly 4 columns of same datatype as in columns in the select below
  FROM Grade   
WHERE grade IN ('MG', '1', '9') --Check for Missing grade or grade 1 or grade 9
UNION  
SELECT StaffNo, Name, DOB, ReportsTo
  FROM Staff  
ORDER BY DOB DESC;
```

Or these are two entirely different queries like-

```
SELECT * FROM Grade   
WHERE grade IN ('MG','1', '9');

SELECT StaffNo, Name, DOB, ReportsTo  --* means all columns so its either * or just the column name specifically. Both can be done, but doesn't make sense
FROM Staff  
ORDER BY DOB DESC;
```

2.`’` is a wrong character in Oracle, it should rather be `'`.

3.In the second `SELECT` the column `ReportsTo` ends with a `,`. This will be considered illegal by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem, for potentially two reasons:

```
WHERE grade = ‘MG’ ‘1-9’
```

Have you *actually* included curly quotes in your query? If so, that's probably why Oracle is complaining about an invalid character.

However, it's then unclear exactly what you're trying to match. Do you want anything starting with MG and then a character between 1 and 9? If so, you could use:

```
WHERE grade BETWEEN 'MG1' AND 'MG9'
```

If that's *not* what you mean, you need to explain what you're trying to do more carefully - and understand that if a *human* can't understand your intention, it's even less likely that a SQL parser will...

Comment: Thanks that is what I meant, sorry bit of a newbie to SQL. I am now getting error code ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended?

Comment: @jeremy: see my comment. Each statement needs to be terminated with a `;`

Comment: @jeremy: I would suggest starting with a good SQL tutorial, and interactively starting off with a *simple* query, then gradually making it more complicated.

Comment: I've managed to sort it eventually! Think that tutorial might be required. Thanks for your help.